Stabilizer of a subspace of a representation of an affine group
In Chapter VIII, Prop 12.1, of this note by JS Milne (as well as Chapter 4, Prop 4.3, of his book, Algebraic Groups: The Theory of Group Schemes of Finite Type over a Field), the following definition of stabilizer is given:
Let $k$ be a field and $G: \mathbf{Alg}_k \to \mathbf{Set}$ an affine group (i.e., representable by a Hopf algebra and factors through $\mathbf{Grp}$). Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space and $\operatorname{GL}_V$ the affine group $R \mapsto \operatorname{GL}(V \otimes_k R)$. Let $r: G \to \operatorname{GL}_V$ be a representation of $G$. For a $k$-subspace $W \subset V$, the stabilizer of $W$ is the affine subgroup $G_W$ of $G$ sending an $k$-algebra $R$ to the group
$$\{g \in G(R) : r_R(g)(W \otimes_k R) = W \otimes_k R\}$$
I find this definition a bit weird. In the old sense (from undergraduate rep theory), an element in the stabilizer should, well, stabilize that subspace, and we never require equality. So, what is the significance of the equality, and do you really need the equality? Can you not just get away by requiring $r_R(g)(W \otimes_k R) \subset W \otimes_k R$? Since the definition is identical in both references, I highly doubt that it is a typo.

The inequality and the inclusion are the same condition for an element of a group acting on a finite-dimensional vector space. Stating it as an identity makes it clearer that this condition is actually a polynomial condition on $g$ (since it is equivalent to fixing a point in the Grassmannian, say); otherwise it's not totally clear that this should still be an affine group scheme.

I somehow still don't see the equivalence. I think there is a very stupid counterexample where the group acts on the entire vector space trivially (i.e. send everything to 0)

Never mind, I somehow forget the fact that $k$ is a field. That makes sense now from linear algebra.

An element of a group can’t do that, because it acts invertibly.
